Assign Bucket Permissions to Users Who Created That Bucket
I created a user and policy which allows an IAM user to create an s3 Bucket. I also want that user to have full permissions on the bucket that they create but not on any other existing bucket. How would I go about that?
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::buckets-created-by-this-user/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::buckets-created-by-this-user",
            ]
        }
    ]
}

